# Creating button in Symfony2 forms

Tags: php, symfony

Does symfony2 have simple button type(not submit or file) for forms?
I looked there(http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) and could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since you don't bind data to a button, it doesn't make sense to have a type for it. Do it using plain HTML.

Answer (score 3):

As an update to this question, as of Symfony 2.3 (released end of may 2013) they do now have button types
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/button.html